# Why is JavaScript variable "undefined" if it is returned from JSON.search()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following code

```
function f () {
  var jsonvar = get (...);
  console.log (jsonvar);
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: transactUrl,
      dataType: "xml",
      success: function (result) {
        console.log (jsonvar);
      }
  });
}

function get (param) {
    return JSON.search (...).toString ();
}
```

and I will have result:

```
"someValue"
undefined
```

But why is `jsonvar` "forgotten" inside of `$.ajax()` function? Variable which is not defined with JSON will have the same value. What is the difference between them? Javascript's `typeof` returns `String` for both of them.

Comment: It definitely shouldn't be, and there's nothing in the code as posted that suggests it's `delete`d. What's `JSON.search()`?

Comment: What is `JSON.search`?

Comment: A variable cannot "forget" a value and neither a *string* nor a *String* can be mutated. I doubt that code accurately shows the problem and/or behavior.

Comment: @epascarello Should not matter with ".toString ();" and "Javascript's typeof returns String for both of them." (although the latter is, at best, a misrepresentation of the query used).

Comment: Please show the code that causes "Javascript's typeof returns **String** for both of them." - as this not a valid return value for `typeof`.

Comment: @blgt @epascarello I'm maintaining the code so not everything is clear to me, and I think that `JSON.search` is from `defiant` library.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have some error somewhere in your code that is (possibly) causing a "silent error". See this fiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/9k1f6dpb/

```
function f () {
    var jsonvar = get();
    console.log (jsonvar);

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'http://updates.html5rocks.com',
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(jsonvar);
        }
    });
}

function get (param) {
    return JSON.search({'a': 1}, '//a').toString();
}

f();
```

This shows that the setup is working and the variable is not "forgotten" along the way. Try adding 'use strict'...it might help throwing useful errors while debugging.

```
function f () {
    'use strict';
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem:

```
ii = "someString";
function f () {
    console.log(ii);
    var ii = 5;
    console.log(ii);
}
f();
```

gives output:

```
undefined
5
```

So the same variable was defined inside of the function. But this is new to me, I thought that variable will exist when it is first time defined.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting

Comment: Yes, this is due to variables being hoisted to the top of their scopes (in this case, the function). But this is not the same set up as in your question.

Comment: I was about to remove applet from code, so I changed `.executeCommand()` to `$.ajax()`. There were multiple variable definitions I didn't notice. That caused the problem.